# Using cuSPARSE in nvGraph as the connection matrix?

Tags: c, cuda, graph-theory, scientific-computing, nvgraph

Title pretty much says it all and I can't find any documentation about this online. I'm interested in implementing a few graph oriented algorithms and my connection matrices are getting rather huge. Is there a way to use cuSPARSE to remove the large amounts of redundancy in my connection matrix? (Since each vertex is connected to really at most 5 others).

I've already implemented graph partitioning to segment and reduce the size of my connection matrix but that leaves me with roughly a 256 x 256 matrix, about half of which is zeros. (Eg: No connection)

Comment: for graph topology, `nvGRAPH` already implements sparse definitions.

Comment: Oh I didnt see that. The documentation on nvgraph seems rather sparse

Edit: Accidental pun

Comment: The documentation is not only "sparse". The wording is horrible as well. CSR and CSC are something that you may have to write down with pen+pencil to wrap your head around. But what essentially are the "column pointers" of the CSC are described as *"Array of size nvertices+1, where i element equals to the number of the first edge for this vertex in the list of all incoming edges in the source_indices array."*. I read it a dozen times, and tried to make sense of it, but failed. In the end, I just verified: These **are** indeed just the column pointers. It's obviously hard to make things easy.

Comment: CSC and CSR are more completely described in [the cusparse documentation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#matrix-formats).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nvGRAPH` is [a new CUDA library](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvgraph) available in the CUDA 8RC toolkit.  Since CUDA 8RC is a release candidate, not a production release version, the documentation for it only exists in PDF form, not officially online, and these PDF documents are installed when you install the CUDA 8 RC toolkit.

The particular document relative to this new library is `nvGRAPH_Library.pdf`, the location of which will vary depending on whether you install the CUDA 8RC toolkit on windows or linux, and options you select during the install process.

> Is there a way to use cuSPARSE to remove the large amounts of redundancy in my connection matrix?

In fact, the *only* way to specify the graph topology (which I think is equivalent to your "connection matrix") is via a [compressed sparse method](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#matrix-formats).  The actual method you use (CSC or CSR) is specified during `nvGRAPH` configuration/initialization, using the `nvgraphTopologyType_t` enum:

```
2.2. nvGRAPH graph topology types

Graphs toplogy types. Defines storage format. Some algorithms can work only with
specific topology types, see algorithms descriptions for the list of supported topologies.

typedef enum
{
NVGRAPH_CSR_32 = 0,
NVGRAPH_CSC_32 = 1,
} nvgraphTopologyType_t;

Topology types

NVGRAPH_CSR_32 Compressed Sparse Rows format (row major format). Used
in SrSPMV algorithm. Use nvgraphCSRTopologyX_t topology
structure for this format.

NVGRAPH_CSC_32 Compressed Sparse Column format (column major format).
Used in SSSP, WidestPath and Pagerank algorithms. Use
nvgraphCSCTopologyX_t topology structure for this format.
```

This particular enum type would normally be passed to `nvGRAPH` during initial graph configuration:

```
// Set graph connectivity and properties (transfers)
nvgraphSetGraphStructure(handle, graph, (void*)CSC_input,NVGRAPH_CSC_32);
```

More complete code samples/examples are given in the `nvGRAPH` documentation PDF document in chapter 3 starting on 20, and there are new `nvGRAPH` sample codes provided in the CUDA 8RC sample codes installation such as `nvgraph_Pagerank`, `nvgraph_SemiRingSpMV`, and `nvgraph_SSSP` (Single Source Shortest Path).

Normal NVIDIA practice is to make these documents available publicly (e.g. [here](http://docs.nvidia.com)) at the point when the toolkit goes to a production release status.

EDIT: with the release of CUDA 8, these documents referenced above are now [publicly available](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/index.html#axzz4U3CInciS).